# Wheel Mesh Not rotating with Wheel Collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wheelcollider

So I'm working on a racing game but first need to get my wheel collider and wheel mesh functioning properly but for some reason they don't appear to be in sync. The wheel colliders rotate for steering and for acceleration but the wheel mesh does not follow, instead it stays idle when testing.

This is the code I have used to get the vehicle moving and wheel colliders spinning which is supposedly meant to make the wheel mesh spin also.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class AxleCougarInfo {   
    public WheelCollider LeftWheel;
    public GameObject LeftWheelMesh;
    public WheelCollider RightWheel;
    public GameObject RightWheelMesh;
    public bool motor;
    public bool steering;
}

public class CougarController : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<AxleCougarInfo> axleInfos;
    public float maxMotorTorque;
    public float maxSteeringAngle;

    public void ApplyLocalPositionToVisual(AxleCougarInfo wheelPair)
    {
        wheelPair.LeftWheelMesh.transform.Rotate (Vector3.left, Time.deltaTime * wheelPair.LeftWheel.rpm * 10, Space.Self);
        wheelPair.RightWheelMesh.transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, Time.deltaTime * wheelPair.RightWheel.rpm * 10, Space.Self);
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    public void FixedUpdate() {

        float motor = maxMotorTorque * Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float steering = maxSteeringAngle * Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        foreach (AxleCougarInfo axleInfo in axleInfos) 
        {
            if (axleInfo.steering == true) 
            {
                axleInfo.LeftWheel.steerAngle = steering;
                axleInfo.RightWheel.steerAngle = steering;
            }

            if (axleInfo.motor == true) 
            {
                axleInfo.LeftWheel.motorTorque = motor;
                axleInfo.RightWheel.motorTorque = motor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, seems your a first time poster here. Just some tips to get a better answer faster! Firstly, double check that your grammar and spelling is correct before submitting. Without this step some people may interpret your question as lacking effort and as a result not want to devote any of their effort to it. Secondly, try to narrow the scope of code you present. It's much easier for us to help you if we can quickly sort through your code to find the error(s). Lastly, be as specific as possible. Thoroughly explain your issue and the steps you've taken to try to resolve it so far.

Comment: I cannot see where you call your function `public void ApplyLocalPositionToVisual()` . I guess this is the function which should rotate your mesh?

Comment: thanks man appreciate the help! @EmreE